# how can i consolidate this expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm removing the initial "The" and spaces of band names for concatenating into a url.
I have this, but it's ugly and I'd like to consolidate into one expression.

```
@artist.sub!(/[Tt]he/, '')
@artist.gsub!(/\s+/, '')
```

Comment: Why does it have to be in one regex? That only results in a more complicated pattern that is harder to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
@artist.gsub!(/(\A[Tt]he)|(\s+)/, '')
```

Comment: That will get rid of "the" in the middle of the expression.

Comment: @EricWalker: True, but there's no way to consolidate and do both with only beginning thes.

Comment: This strips all spaces and doesn't account for boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

You can of course chain `#sub` and `#gsub` expressions; e.g.,

```
@artist = @artist.sub(/^[Tt]he/, '').gsub(/\s+/, '')
```

Any more compact and I would hesitate to call it elegant—just clever (and unclear).

Note the use of `#sub` and `#gsub` instead of `#sub!` and `#gsub!`.  Per @pguardiario's comment, the second two will return nil if there is no match, causing a `NoMethodError` exception. Also, note that this has an anchor to prevent "The" from being removed from the middle of the string.

If you're trying to create a slug for use in URLs, you might be better going with a method in a library.

Comment: +1 for a more maintainable method. If the OP is replacing space-runs with single spaces, I'd probably not use `\s`, and use `' '` instead, or switch to using `squeeze(' ')`.

Comment: Careful, `sub!` returns nil if there's no match. Also include boundaries or you will get in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
@artist = @artist.sub(/\Athe\b/i, '').strip
```

Comment: You need something to get rid of the whitespace as well (the second line in the OP's question).

Comment: @Eric Walker - `strip` will remove initial spaces.

Comment: rightly or wrongly, he's going for whitespace in the middle as well.

Comment: After reading it again, I can't tell. It's ambiguously worded.

Comment: I think your interpretation makes more sense than removing whitespace in the middle.

Comment: @EricWalker: He's going for strings to use in URLs. Spaces anywhere not accepted.